# Python regex - conditional matching?

Tags: python, regex

I don't know if that's the right word for it, but I am trying to come up with some regex's that can extract coefficients and exponents from a mathematical expression.  The expression will come in the form 'axB+cxD+exF' where the lower case letters are the coefficients and the uppercase letters are the exponents.  I have a regex that can match to both of them, but I'm wondering if I can use 2 regexs, one to match the coefficients and one for the exponents.  Is there a way to match a number with a letter on one side of it without matching the letter?  EG, in '3x3+6x2+2x1+8x0' I need to get
    ['3', '6', '2', '8']
and
    ['3', '2', '1', '0']

Comment: I am just added the signs to the coefficients...if there is a + then I ignore it, and the coefficient right next to it is left positive.  If there is a - then I pick it up by just adding a -* just before the \d, it works just fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [positive look-ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead) to match something that is followed by something else. To match the coefficients, you can use:

```
>>> s = '3x3+6x2+2x1+8x0'
>>> re.findall(r'\d+(?=x)', s)
['3', '6', '2', '8']
```

From the documentation of the [`re`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) module:

> (?=...)
>       Matches if ... matches next, but doesn’t consume any of the string.
>   This is called a lookahead assertion.
>   For example, Isaac (?=Asimov) will
>   match 'Isaac ' only if it’s followed
>   by 'Asimov'.

For the exponents, you can use [positive look-behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind) instead:

```
>>> s = '3x3+6x2+2x1+8x0'
>>> re.findall(r'(?<=x)\d+', s)
['3', '2', '1', '0']
```

Again, from the docs:

> (?<=...) Matches if the current position in the string is preceded by a match for
>   ... that ends at the current position.
>   This is called a positive lookbehind
>   assertion. (?<=abc)def will find a
>   match in abcdef, since the lookbehind
>   will back up 3 characters and check if
>   the contained pattern matches.

Comment: Nice work.  I can't recall having read a better explanation of positive look-ahead/look-behind.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import re
>>> equation = '3x3+6x2+2x1+8x0'
>>> re.findall(r'x([0-9]+)', equation)
['3', '2', '1', '0']
>>> re.findall(r'([0-9]+)x', equation)
['3', '6', '2', '8']
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way to do it, without regex:

```
>>> eq = '3x3+6x2+2x1+8x0'
>>> op = eq.split('+')
['3x3', '6x2', '2x1', '8x0']
>>> [o.split('x')[0] for o in op]
['3', '6', '2', '8']
>>> [o.split('x')[1] for o in op]
['3', '2', '1', '0']
```